# Loop is breaking in a wrong place in python

Tags: python

I wrote this code in python. It's a part of a large code file. I explained my problem after the code below.

```
def main():
    maxAttempt = 5
    endLoop = False
    isFailed = False
    words = ['a', 'apple']
    loop = True
    for word in words:
        while loop != False:
            print(word)
            uResult = input(
                f'Enter the word: ').upper()
            if uResult == word.upper():
                print('Congrats!')
                loop = False
                # The loop is breaking here
            else:
                maxAttempt -= 1
                if maxAttempt == 0:
                    isFailed = True
                    break
                print('try again')
        if endLoop:
            break

    if not isFailed:
        print('Congrats! You are safe now.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to break the `for` loop if the `endLoop` is `True`. But the loop is breaking right after executing the `if` block -

```
if uResult == word.upper():
                print('Congrats!')
                loop = False
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve this? 
Hope I was able to explain my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a problem, you negate the while loop condition and then there isn't anything else in that iteration of the loop. `endLoop` refers to the outer for loop

Comment: I've edited the problem. Please have a look now. there was a mistake in my writing.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have both `loop` and `endLoop`?  In particular, you never set the latter to `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say the loop is breaking where you have pointed out. After `loop = False`, you correctly end the `while` loop and move onto the next entry in the `words` list. However, at this point `loop` is still false, so you will never enter the while loop, so it appears like the loop is breaking, when really you are iterating over the list of words correctly, just not entering the for loop.

Instead something like:

```
for word in words:
    loop = True
    while loop:
         <Processing code goes here>
```

So each iteration of you for loop, you make sure that the while loop will be entered at least once.

Answer (score 1):

`loop` stays `False` after the first word, that is why. You should initialize it inside the `for`:

```
for word in words:
    loop = True
    while loop:
```